# Start all torrents when computer is idle

Tags: bittorrent

I have this huge list of torrents to download and I use bittorrent. Does bittorrent or any client have an option to pause all torrents when PC is working and start them when PC is idle ?

Comment: Which operating system? rTorrent for *nix takes XML-RPC calls and can quite easily be scripted in this and other manners.

Answer (score 2):

in standard bittorrent there's an option in the bandwidth options 'stop transers on user interaction', that's probably what you need, may be very similar in others.